# Will github support common jekyll plugins?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I would like to know whether github support common Jekyll plugins like those used for code minification, concatenation, uglification etc, as a part of learning Jekyll. I'm planning to host my site in GitHub.
This might be a very basic question, but being a newbie to Jekyll, please help me to know about this.

Comment: Shouldn't you [ask this on github](https://github.com/support)?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: No, but you probably won't need it to.

## The "No" Part

Github supports those plugins supported by the Github pages gem. See here: https://help.github.com/articles/adding-jekyll-plugins-to-a-github-pages-site/

The supported list evolves, but the current list can be seen here: https://pages.github.com/versions/

I understand the tasks you are after are not supported by any of those at the time of writing.

## The Other Part

The way most people use Jekyll means you do not need Github to do the processing.

The process is normally:

1. Create on your computer a local git clone repository of the repository on Github.
2. Do your work locally where the plugins *will* work - or any grunt / gulp tasks you will probably end up using instead.
3. Then push the updated files back up to github - allowing the now "processed" contents of `_site` folder to be hosted on github pages **and** telling github NOT to re-process your files again using jekyll by including an empty `.nojekyll` file in your root folder.

Others will explain it better than I, but that is the general gist.

Have fun!

**EDIT:** Updated per @David Jacques comment

Comment: Good answer. At point 3, you need to add an empty `.nojekyll` file in order to gh pages not to jekyll process your pages.